# Sorting integers based on their prime factors

Tags: c, sorting, integer, primes, factors

I am kind of stuck how to sort integers based on their greatest prime factor in ascending order. For example, we have 3 and 8. The order should be: 8, 3 because 8's prime factor (2) is less than 3's prime factor (3). If we have the same greatest prime factor for 2 numbers like 9 and 27, then the smaller number should be first. In this order: 9, 27

Okay, here's my code, but it needs some modification.

```
long long sort(long long integers[], long long primes[]) {
    /* loop variables */
    int i, j;
    /* temporary variable */
    long long tmp;

    for (i = (SIZE - 1); i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (integers[j-1] > integers[j]) {
                tmp = integers[j-1];
                integers[j-1] = integers[j];
                integers[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is also important to mention that integers[i]'s greatest prime factor is stored as primes[i]. Primes are already all set up and good, this thing only needs correct sorting.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Self-vandalism rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you just need to use `primes` somewhere.  In your current code you aren't using that variable at all, and it seems rather clear where it should go.

Bonus tip: look up the standard C library function `qsort`.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what condition to have. I've tried this: if (integers[j-1] > integers[j] && primes[j-1] >= primes[j]), but it's not what is expected. Could you help please? I think I will leave qsort for another time though.

Comment: Just think harder about that condition--you're almost there.  Just think about what exactly the condition is for two elements to be considered "out of order."  It's not quite what you just wrote.

Comment: Okay, I just did it with a bit longer code than I think it should be, but it works. Thanks.

I will use qsort next time. I just come from Java background, and I'm not entirely familiar with C's libraries.